# 1Tb PCIe SSD in 2012 Retina MacBook Pro?

Tags: ssd, macbook-pro

Now that the late 2013 Retina MacBook Pro can be configured with Samsung based 1TB PCIe based SSD storage, would those fit into the late 2012 Retina MacBook Pro?

[OWC describes about the 1TB configuration](http://blog.macsales.com/20816-owcs-definitive-quick-guide-to-making-the-most-of-2013-macbook-pro-with-retina-display), but not about the specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the 2012 and early-2013 Retina MBP SSD's are not PCIe-based, so you could not install an SSD from a late-2013 Retina MBP.